# How do I make a slight modification to a package locally in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using a [package](https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-font-awesome) that loads Font Awesome from a CDN. However, the CDN used is pretty terrible, often stalling or timing out, so I'd like to switch it out.

The source code is incredibly simple, and looking through it I found this:

```
style.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Switching to a different CDN would only require changing this one line (I presume), but the problem is I don't know how! Or rather, I don't know *where* it is available in my project.

How do I actually do this?

Comment: @Yeats I cover this topic in my blog post on [local pacakges](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a packages/ directory at the top level directory of your app (myapp/packages) and simply git clone the package you want to modify into it.

Add the package via `meteor add` and you'll be able to edit the files of the package you just cloned.

Comment: Meteor will automatically look there first and if it doesn't find it look for it online? Edit: What I'm trying to ask is what to type...

Comment: You can use the `meteor list` command and Meteor will indicate there's a local copy (which will be used instead).